# Way to skip, pause songs rhythmbox when screen locked?

Tags: 14.04, rhythmbox, music

How can I skip a song when the screen is locked?  I use the short cut keys when its not locked, and I hate having to log back in when screen is locked just to skip a song.

Comment: You could consider not locking the screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using GDM as a lockscreen instead lightdm, it features music controls on the lockscreen when music is playing, like on a android phones lockscreen.

However I don't know if keyboard shortcuts will work as the lockscreen is supposed to prevent anyone using the computer while it is locked, so keyboard access to the desktop may be locked out.

Install it

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

Start it

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

Stop lightdm, so you don't have two lockscreens

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

If the music controls don't show

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver show-notifications true
```

To switch back to lightdm

```
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm && service gdm stop
```